# Test whether a value in a cell matches another value in an array, and do an action if a match is found

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to create a formula that will look at a cell and test the value in that cell against an array or multiple arrays of cells, and if a match is found, take another action like calculate a mathematical formula.

Really the action taken afterwards is not the issue, just used as a reference of what I ultimately intend to do with the formula. The biggest hurdle I am having is the first part of the formula where I need to test values.

[image: Can't embed image, so here is a link]

I need to test the employee ID's in column W against the same employee ID's located in the "doors" columns and see if there is a match, and if there is, do another action.

Formulas I have tried, though I really don't know what I should be doing here:

```
{=IF(W5=T4:T7,"true")}

{=IF(OR(F4:F7,H4:H7,J4:J7,L4:L7,N4:N7,P4:P7,R4:R7,T4:T7)=W6,"True")}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Please let me know if I need to elaborate.

Comment: What should be returned, it will help us with getting you the correct formula.

Comment: Honestly just a True statement I suppose. I want to test and see if there is a match, and if there is, divide the corresponding number in column X by 5,000, and then multiply that result by 1,000,000. Hopefully that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use MATCH for one column:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(W6,$T$4:$T$7)),X6/5000*1000000,0)
```

For multiple columns:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($B$4$:$T$7)/($B$4$:$T$7=W6),1)),X6/5000*1000000,0)
```

Comment: That's perfect and exactly what I needed. Much appreciated!